# Why does null-forgiving operator (!) does not work for parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, null, roslyn, nullable-reference-types

Consider the following xUnit Test (this is the most popular and annoying case I have):

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var result = await this.FindAsync();

        Assert.NotNull(result); // Line 1
        Assert.Equal(3, result.Length); // Line 2: Null warning here
        Assert.Equal("yes", result.ToLower()); // Line 3
    }

    // I use async to demonstrate a shortcoming of workaround
    async Task<string?> FindAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult("Yes");
    }

}
```

As xUnit does not have `[NotNull]` annotations yet, the compiler does not know `result` cannot be `null` from there onwards. However if I mark it as "not null" at line 1, it does not work:

```cs
        Assert.NotNull(result!); // Tooltip says "result" is not null here
        Assert.Equal(3, result.Length); // But here it says "result" may be null
```

[image]

[image]

These workaround works but have shortcoming:

```cs
// Mark as not null at the assignment:
// - Has to add parentheses in many cases
// - Does not work if it may actually be null
var result = (await this.FindAsync())!;

// Mark on the first usage, like at line 2:
// This has to be at the first line.
// If you move code around or remove it, you get the warning back and have to move the ! around
Assert.Equal(3, result!.Length);
```

Why can't it "just" work if I put `!` at line 1 `Assert.NotNull(result!);`? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: There's no warning on line 1, so there's nothing for the `!` to suppress, so it has no effect

Comment: @canton7 while you may be right, that makes the operator so counter-intuitive. When I use `!`, I want the compiler to know that from there onward, it's not null, not just "don't send warning here"

Comment: That's not what it does. It is used at a particular point in code to suppress a nullable warning at that point. It's not an annotation which means "This object cannot be null here", it means "Shut up about this specific warning generated here"

Comment: @canton7 Well, again, you may be right and seem likely that's what happens but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) *seems* to suggest what I thought: "you use the null-forgiving operator to declare that expression x of a reference type isn't null". I.e. my expression (`result`) is not null there, so from then on, it should not be null unless I reassign it.

Comment: @LukeVo: The documentation is talking about the specific expression on which you place the `!`. It does not state "and every expression henceforth".

Comment: @Flater Sorry to disagree. If what you say is true, then line 3 should still have warning since line 3 doesn't have `!`. It's inconsistent between line 1 to 2 and 2 to 3.

Comment: @Flater it's C# 8+ Nullable-Reference Type. `string?` and `string` are different. One may be null and the other *should* not.

Comment: Line 3 doesn't have a warning because the compiler knows that, if `result` is `null`, line 2 would have thrown a `NullReferenceException` making line 3 unreachable

Comment: @LukeVo: Earlier warnings can preclude later warnings. If you comment out line 2, line 3 will get a warning.

Comment: @LukeVo there is no warning on line 3 cause compiler knows that if `result` is `null` exception will be thrown on line 2. null-forgiving operator has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @canton7 ah right. I concede that point. Make sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding xUnit*, newer versions of xUnit do support null annotations. For example, version `2.4.2-pre.13`. This is currently in pre-release, but it works well in my experience.

*Regarding seeing warnings after the first suppression*, it depends upon what is suppressed.

This does not warn:

```cs
object? o = null;
o!.ToString();
o.ToString(); // no warning
```

This does warn:

```cs
object? o = null;
object j = o!;
o.ToString(); // warning
```

One could reasonably argue that the second case should not warn. Perhaps open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn to ask about this. It does seem like it could improve the experience of using nullable reference types.

Comment: Thanks, I [submitted one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58603) and they concluded it's their design decision.